# appSettings config gets ignored before I can validate them

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, config, appsettings

The config in appSettings that I want to validate looks like this:

```
"ListOfWork": [
    {
      "Name": "Work-1",
      "StartDate": "2020-01-01",
      "EndDate": "2021-01-01"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Work-2",
      "StartDate": "2021-01-01",
      "EndDate": "invaliddate"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Work-3",
      "StartDate": "2022-01-01",
      "EndDate": "20231-01-01"
    }
]
```

The `Work` Class looks like this:

```
public class Work
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I'm fetching the config in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.Configure<List<Work>>(Configuration.GetSection("ListOfWork"));
```

For the given example of the config, I would like to validate that the values provided in the appSettings is good and we do the validations in our automated validations UTests but even before that, the object with invalid attribute is already rejected and the only `Work` objects I get are `Work-1` and `Work-3`.

Is there any way I could raise an error instead of just having the invalid object ignored?

Answer (score 0):

By default the properties from appsettings are not picked up automatically if there are parsing errors. In your case "invaliddate" it's a string and the conversion to DateTime? it's not possible. I'd suggest to slightly adjust the Work class to define string properties instead of DateTime properties and you can have only getters for the DateTime props:

```
 public class Work
{
    private DateTime _startDateTime;
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string? StartDate { get; set; }

    public string? EndDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? StartDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            var isDateTime = DateTime.TryParse(StartDate, out var startDate);
            return isDateTime? startDate: null;
            
        }
    }

    public DateTime? EndDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            var isDateTime = DateTime.TryParse(EndDate, out var endDate);
            return isDateTime ? endDate : null;

        }
    }
}
```

In this way the parsing will be successful and you could check the validity of the datetime in the DateTime getters.
Note that I am using C# 10 features, you may not be able to fully run this code snippet if you re using an older version, but I thing you get the point and you can come up with your own implementation.